# Is it a better way to use active record to realize this sql?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
select t1.id, t1.title from posts t1
inner join (select title, body from posts group by title) as t2 on t1.title = t2.title where title = ?
```

Have tried:

```
Post
  .select(:id, :title)
  .joins('INNER JOIN (SELECT title, body from posts AS t2)')
  .group(:title)
  .where('title = ?', title)
```

Don't know how to set `t1` to the it.

If not, maybe the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` is the only way.

## More details

For this sql:

```
p = Post.select("t1.title")
        .from("posts t1")
        .joins("INNER JOIN (SELECT title, MAX(id) AS maxID FROM posts WHERE category_id = ? GROUP GY title) AS t2 ON t1.title = t2.title AND t1.id = t2.maxID", 1)
```

Why can't set parameter `category_id` in `joins` method here?

After run this source, `p.title` got `NoMethodError: undefined method title`.

Comment: Isn’t this just: Post.where(‘title = ?’, title)

Comment: I know it creates other SQL, but I don’t see what you achieve with using the join in this case.

Comment: You can possibly do it using `#from` as described in the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/from).

Comment: @moveson It looks fine. Thank you.

Comment: @bo-oz I have added more details for the goal.

Comment: You still haven’t given context on why you need such a query... can you explain in which use case you need such a query? You are only selecting fields from t1, so why the complex join with t2? Please describe what you would like this query to do...

Comment: @bo-oz It's select t1, but should match the conditions with t2. Even they are the same table.

Comment: Ok, as you are not giving any additional context, I’m not going to provide any additional support on this question. Sorry. Good luck solving this problem.

Comment: @bo-oz Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` instead.